# Programmatically getting the per-core CPU load for a Windows system

Tags: c, windows, cpu-usage, cpu-cores

I am trying to programmatically determine what the idle/running break-down is for the CPU cores.

In Linux, I use `/proc/stat` for this, which gives me cycle counts for cycles spent in:

- user: normal processes executing in user mode
- nice: niced processes executing in user mode
- system: processes executing in kernel mode
- idle: twiddling thumbs
- iowait: waiting for I/O to complete
- irq: servicing interrupts
- softirq: servicing softirqs

Please note: I am getting system-wide numbers, not the cpu-usage for a specific process!

Now, I want to do the same, but in C, for a Windows system.

### UPDATE

I've been able to [find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getsystemtimes) an aggregate statistic, so not per core: `GetSystemTimes()` which will return a value for idle, kernel and user cycles. What really confused me at first, is that the kernel cycles include idle cycles.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/perfctrs/about-performance-counters

Comment: if you want the saame code probably cygwin will help